# Convert Dictionary<int, List<string>> to IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I need to create a class that:

- manipulates a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` internally
- exposes it as a property of type `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>>`

The latter requirement cannot be changed unfortunately. Due to the (understandable) limitations of covariance in C#, the following does not work:

```
private Dictionary<int, List<string>> things;
public IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>> Things => things; // compile time error
```

The class needs to mutate the dictionary and the lists, so I cannot change the private field to be of the interface type.

*What is the most succinct way, preferably using Linq, to convert a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` to an `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>>`?*

Comment: Why not keep it as `private Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>> things;` and then cast the value back to `List<string>` internally when you want to modify the collection?

Comment: Could it be that you are looking for : `... => Things.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value);` (an implicit cast of values)

Comment: @Igor because I need to add elements to the lists

Comment: @Fabjan That would make a copy of the dictionary, but I think you would also need `Things.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value.AsEnumerable())` or a cast on the value to `IEnumerable<string>` to get the right dictionary type.

Comment: ... which is why I suggested the cast. Internally (in the class) you know its a `List<string>`. You can also add a convenience method if you want in the class. Example code inside that class: `void someThingThatAdds(){ ((List<string>) this.things[32]).Add("new string");`

Comment: Thanks Igor, I could solve it this way, even though I had to specify the generic argumetns explicitly.